# Quickly reset the computers in my cyber cafe to a default state

Tags: windows

I'm running a cyber cafe and getting a headache when people use the PC and install anything on that.

I am looking for some software so, when we reboot the computer, all data and Windows will return back to my previous settings. That way I don't care if people want to install or create anything on the PC because after reboot, the computer will reset back to my default setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're after [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/). This is the main product used for this in the corporate world. It's not free (45.00 CAD for the standard version), but it is well worth every penny.

> Faronics Deep Freeze helps eliminate
>   workstation damage and downtime by
>   making computer configurations
>   indestructible. Once Deep Freeze is
>   installed on a workstation, any
>   changes made to the
>   computer—regardless of whether they
>   are accidental or malicious—are never
>   permanent. Deep Freeze provides
>   immediate immunity from many of the
>   problems that plague computers
>   today—inevitable configuration drift,
>   accidental system misconfiguration,
>   malicious software activity, and
>   incidental system degradation.
>
> Deep Freeze ensures computers are
>   absolutely bulletproof, even when
>   users have full access to system
>   software and settings. Users get to
>   enjoy a pristine and unrestricted
>   computing experience, while IT
>   personnel are freed from tedious
>   helpdesk requests, constant system
>   maintenance, and continuous
>   configuration drift.

Similar products include [Smart Restart](http://centuriontech.com/smartrestart/) and [Shadow User](http://www.storagecraft.com/shadow_user.php), both commercial as well.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has its own tool, since at least windows XP- its called windows [steadystate](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/sharedaccess/default.mspx)
-Its free too

Comment: Nice! (And a good example of a question which had an accepted answer too soon, I guess!)

Comment: Never too late to change accepted answers...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Returnil? http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/

from the home page of the product:

> Returnil's products combine virus protection with powerful system
>   restore feature which lets you sleep at night knowing your computer is
>   protected! Simple Fix Restart your PC and "pooof", all the bad
>   neighbourhood stuff making havoc on your computer including any
>   malicious files are gone. Your PC stays nice and clean

Comment: Why this software? what does it do? Rather than just provide a link, please provide an answer for why this will be effective for the OP.

Comment: from the home page of the product http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/: Returnil's products combine virus protection with powerful system restore feature which lets you sleep at night knowing your computer is protected! 

Simple Fix

Restart your PC and "pooof", all the bad neighbourhood stuff making havoc on your computer including any malicious files are gone. Your PC stays nice and clean.